# Счетчик времени на Джаваскрипт

Tags: javascript

Сумел с костылями закодить такой вот счетчик.Не подскажете как сделать бесконечный цикл,чтобы таймер шел с 0 до бесконечности.Совсем запутался, проблемы с синтаксисом

```js
while
window.onload = function() {
  function timer() {

    var hour = document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML;
    var minute = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML;
    var end = false;

    if (second > 0) second--;
    else {
      second = 59;

      if (minute > 0) minute--;
      else {
        second = 59;

        if (hour > 0) hour--;
        else end = true;
      }
    }

    if (end) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      alert("Таймер сработал!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = hour;
      document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = minute;
      document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = second;
    }
  }
  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf8'>
  <title>Создаем таймер обратного отсчета - Seo блог sergey-oganesyan.ru</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="timer">
    <div id="hour">11</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="minute">56</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="second">45</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var d = +new Date(2018, 05, 05);
  setInterval(function() {
    var t = new Date;
    t.setTime(d += 1000);

    var s = t.getSeconds();
    var h = t.getHours();
    var m = t.getMinutes();

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <span class="hour">hh</span>:<span class="min">mm</span>:<span class="sec">ss</span>
</div>
```

Comment: О!Спасибо!Точно

Answer (score 0):

Вынес на верх функцию и добавил **window.intervalID** в функцию clearInterval.

```js
var timer = function() {

    var hour = document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML;
    var minute = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML;
    var end = false;

    if (second > 0) second--;
    else {
      second = 59;

      if (minute > 0) minute--;
      else {
        second = 59;

        if (hour > 0) hour--;
        else end = true;
      }
    }

    if (end) {
      clearInterval(window.intervalID);
      console.log("Таймер сработал!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = hour;
      document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = minute;
      document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = second;
    }
  }

window.onload = function() {
  window.intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  timer();
}
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <div id="timer">
    <div id="hour">11</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="minute">56</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="second">45</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hour = document.getElementById('hour');
var minute = document.getElementById('minute');
var second = document.getElementById('second');

function tic() {

  var time_hour = Number(hour.innerText);
  var time_minute = Number(minute.innerText);
  var time_second = Number(second.innerText);

  time_second++;

  if (time_second >= 59) {
    time_minute++;
    time_second = 0;
    if (time_minute >= 59) {
      time_hour++;
      time_minute = 0;
    }
  }
  hour.innerHTML = time_hour;
  minute.innerHTML = time_minute;
  second.innerHTML = time_second;

  if (time_hour == 11 && time_minute == 12 && time_second == 34) {
    clearInterval(Iteration);
  }
}
var Iteration = setInterval(tic, 10);
```

```css
#timer {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

#timer div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf8'>
  <title>Создаем таймер обратного отсчета - Seo блог sergey-oganesyan.ru</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="timer">
    <div id="hour">11</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="minute">10</div>&nbsp;:
    <div id="second">34</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: так это с 10, нужно с 0

Comment: Вы можте сами выставить время в хтмл

Comment: так идет то он обратно.а мне надо 0,1,2 и тд

Comment: В примере идет обратный отчет

Comment: исправил, так??